# Shuffling a deck for randomness

Tags: statistics, gambling

I am trying to do some research into shuffling decks of cards. Most information I come across is too basic, doesn't have an answer or doesn't give the information I am looking for. I have heard that 7 riffle shuffles will randomize a 52 card with 4 of kinds, what I am interested in, is in bigger, smaller and decks with less matching kinds. I wanted to do the math for a 40 card, 60 card and 100 card deck to see how many shuffles it takes to fully randomize. any leads would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This paper](http://www.dartmouth.edu/~chance/teaching_aids/Mann.pdf) describes how to compute that seven is about the right number.  It won't vary much for different deck sizes, growing slowly.  The abstract to [this paper](http://rspa.royalsocietypublishing.org/content/456/2002/2561) says it asymptotically takes about $\frac 32 \log_2 n$ shuffles to get a reasonable mix.   I don't have access to the paper.  For a $52$ card deck this is $8.5$